# How can I add a data to the another activity in a Button form

Tags: java, android-studio, button

I'm making an android POS and I have a problem to add a data pass to other activity. When the user is adding a new product, the product will show on the Menu activity in the Button form and has a value whatever the user input in the name and price.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addproduct);

        POSDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        prdName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PrdName);
        prdPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PrdPrice);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnPrdAdd);
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtBack);

    AddProduct();

    }

    public  void AddProduct(){
    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String name = prdName.getText().toString().trim();
            String price = prdPrice.getText().toString().trim();
               if(prdName.length() != 0 && prdPrice.length() != 0)
               {
                   boolean ADD = POSDB.addData(name,price);
                if(ADD == true)
                    {Toast.makeText(Addproduct.this, " The product has been added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                else
                    {Toast.makeText(Addproduct.this, " Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
                }
                else
                    {Toast.makeText(Addproduct.this, " Please fill up the Textfield", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how do you structure the **Menu Activity** to get the data and how it shows it.
For example, If you are using a RecyclerView you can set it to show the data in a list of buttons, so when a new product added to the database it will be shown by RecyclerView in the button form.